# Install AppFabric On windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, appfabric

I'm trying to install AppFabric 1.1 on Windows8.
It setup asks for .net framework 3.5.

Windows 8 is coming with .net framework 4.5.
Why does it ask for .net framework 3.5 ?

What I should do in order to install AppFabric?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can install it with .net framework 4.5. .Here you go:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115

Answer (score 1):

Run the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All
```

See this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx